# How long do I have to wait before being able to go back to Shenzhen again with another Special Economic Zone visa? And how often can I do so?

Tags: visas, china, hong-kong, shenzhen, special-economic-zones

Citizens from most countries  may obtain an entry visa ([Special Economic Zone visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_China&oldid=867954431#Special_Economic_Zone_visa_on_arrival)) when traveling to and staying solely in the Shenzhen Special Economic Zone. The Special Economic Zone visa  for Shenzhen a.k.a. Shenzhen 5-Day Visa on Arrival is  valid for 5 days (the duration of stay starts from the next day of arrival).

If I enter Shenzhen from Hong Kong by train with a Special Economic Zone visa, then go back to Hong Kong, how long do I have to wait before being able to go back to Shenzhen again with another Special Economic Zone visa? And how often can I do so?

---

I am a French citizen. According to https://www.travelchinaguide.com/cityguides/guangdong/shenzhen/visa-on-arrival.htm ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181111011451/https://www.travelchinaguide.com/cityguides/guangdong/shenzhen/visa-on-arrival.htm)), "As of July 2017, French and US citizens qualify for the five-day VOA" (VOA=visa on arrival).

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TUhxIn
- https://redd.it/9y9j3v

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read and been told so far, same day re-entry is fine, but I'm getting conflicting information regarding how often one can obtain the Shenzhen 5-Day Visa on Arrival.

When I asked a Chinese immigration officer while doing the Shenzhen 5-Day Visa on Arrival in December 2018, I was told "you can obtain the visa no more than 3 times per month" and, once I repeated the question to confirm the information, the second answer I got the same officer was slightly different: "less than 3 times per month". So it was unclear whether 3 times would be ok.

Furthermore, someone on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chinavisa/comments/9y9j3v/how_long_do_i_have_to_wait_before_being_able_to/ea0kxj3) reports having lived over 3 months on 5 days SZ visas:

> You can come back same day if you want, **I lived over 3 months on 5 days SZ visas, have over 20 of them in my old passport**. Crossing the border at Luohu and immediately returning back applying for a new 5 day visa. Never had a problem.

In summary, same day re-entry is fine and twice a month is fine, but I'm not sure yet whether one can enter more than twice a month. The visa currently costs 168 RMBs for French citizens (the price depends on the visa applicant's citizenship; 168 RMBs is the most common price).